# when we use @Value{"#user.name"} spel in idea ,it will tell you how to spell ,But when I use my own implementation annotations idea do not tip me

Tags: spring

when we use @Value{"#user.name"} spel in idea  ,it will tell you how  to spell ,But when I use my own implementation annotations idea do not tip me?

Comment: How can Idea get to know about your own annotations? It processes spring annotations because you've enabled the corresponding plugin.

Comment: which plugin can do this?